# X-labels in line plot of matrlx

Tags: matlab, plot

In Matlab, when I want to plot each row of a n x m matrix `A` as a line, I do

```
plot(A');
```

One problem for me is the x-labels which are indices from 1 to number of variables.

I want to change those labels to more meaningful values from, say, a vector `B`.

So I tried following statement

```
plot(repmat(B,1,size(A,1)),A');
```

but the chart looks totally different. I know I can use 'XTickLabel' but it does not work with line plot of matrix, meaning no effect of 'XTickLabel'. Any idea how I can put labels correctly?

Comment: In the example, you are not using `line` but `plot` so XTickLabel should work. In what sense does the " chart looks totally different?" Can you give a working example of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something along the lines of:

```
>> 
A = [
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 8 7 6
5 4 3 2
    ];
>> 
B = [
15 30 45 60
    ];
>> plot(A')
>> set(gca, 'XTick', 1:numel(B))
>> set(gca, 'XTickLabel', cellstr(num2str(B'))')
```

This would give you:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try this as well

```
x = 0:0.1:1;
A = [ x.*x ; exp(-x) ]
plot( x, A' )
```

[image: XLabels]